# Changing a pipe delimited file to comma delimited in VB.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, delimiter, delimited

So I have a set of pipe delimited inputs which are something like this:

> "787291 | 3224325523" | 37826427 | 2482472 | "46284729|46246" | 24682
>   | 82524 | 6846419 | 68247

and I am converting them to comma delimited using the code given below:

```
 Dim line As String
    Dim fields As String()
    Using sw As New StreamWriter("c:\test\output.txt")
        Using tfp As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("c:\test\test.txt")
            tfp.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            tfp.Delimiters = New String() {"|"}
            tfp.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
            While Not tfp.EndOfData
                fields = tfp.ReadFields
                line = String.Join(",", fields)
                sw.WriteLine(line)
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
```

So far so good. It only considers the delimiters that are present outside the quotes and changes them to the comma delimiter. But trouble starts when I have input with a stray quotation like below:

> "787291 | 3224325523" | 37826427 | 2482472 | "46284729|46246" | 24682
>   | **"82524** | 6846419 | 68247

Here the code gives

> MalformeLineExcpetion

Which I realize is due to the stray quotation in my input and since i am like a total noob in RegEx so i am not able to use it here(or I am incapable of). If anyone has any idea, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try `Regex.Replace(line, "(""\b.*?\b"")|""", "$1")`

Comment: I am not sure i Understand as i would have to place this line of code after the "line" is assigned a string value which is not happening as the code gives an exception at the "ReadFields" hence preventing "line" from ever being populated with any value in the first place.

Comment: You'll have to read the input, Regex it (or use any other tool you're confortable with) then use the `TextFieldParser` to parse the fixed input. Fixing the actual source that generates the faulty strings should be a priority, though.

Comment: Isn't it impossible to fix? Is the " supposed to be there? Does it end after the first number, the 2nd, last? There's no way to know.

Comment: @the_lotus I know, it never ends. As i said, its just a stray and unfortunately, i cannot do anything about it cos it is the input that i get. Nothing can be done.

Comment: @Jimi cannot do it, this is what i have unfortunately so have to work with it. To be honest i am not very comfortable with VB itself and this was given to me as a task out of nowhere, so had to do it. So it would be great if you could explain what you are saying in context of my code.

Comment: Well, I thought it was understandable. 1) Read all the lines of the faulty input, 2) fix the faulty input lines 3) Use `TextFieldParser` to perform the parsing of the correct input 4) Join the input parts created by the `TextFieldParser` using `,` as separator 5) Save the input to the final output file. If you want a sample code of the procedure, let me know..

Comment: @Jimi would be great if you could provide a sample code.

Comment: All right, give me a minute.

Comment: It would concern me that I have a stray quote.  How do you know that you can just delete it?

Comment: @dbasnett I get the file from the external source and they have these inputs and we are not allowed to do anything. Whatever needs to be done, is from their end only. Hence, I needed the code to overcome this limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the coded procedure described in the comments:

- Read all the lines of the original input file,
- fix the faulty lines (with Regex or anything else that fits),
- use `TextFieldParser` to perform the parsing of the correct input
- `Join()` the input parts created by `TextFieldParser` using `,` as separator
- save the fixed, reconstructed input lines to the final output file

I'm using [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53883750/changing-a-pipe-delimited-file-to-comma-delimited-in-vb-net#comment94614029_53883750) Regex pattern: it looks like it should work given the description of the problem.

**Note**:
Of course I don't know whether a specific Encoding should be used.
Here, the [Encoding is the default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_WriteAllLines_System_String_System_String___) **`UTF-8 no-BOM`**, in and out.

**`"FaultyInput.txt"`** is the *corrupted* source file.
**`"FixedInput.txt"`** is the file containing the input lines fixed (hopefully) by the Regex. You could also use a `MemoryStream`.
**`"FixedOutput.txt"`** is the final `CSV` file, containing comma separated fields and the correct values.

These files are all read/written in the executable startup path.

```
Dim input As List(Of String) = File.ReadAllLines("FaultyInput.txt").ToList()
For line As Integer = 0 To input.Count - 1
    input(line) = Regex.Replace(input(line), "(""\b.*?\b"")|""", "$1")
Next

File.WriteAllLines("FixedInput.txt", input)

Dim output As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
Using tfp As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("FixedInput.txt")
    tfp.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    tfp.Delimiters = New String() {"|"}
    tfp.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
    While Not tfp.EndOfData
        Dim fields As String() = tfp.ReadFields
        output.Add(String.Join(",", fields))
    End While
End Using

File.WriteAllLines("FixedOutput.txt", output)
'Eventually...
'File.Delete("FixedInput.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, It is working so far. I will test it with different inputs and see if it holds up all right. But seriously man, I cannot thank you enough. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ReadMalformedCSV()
    Dim s$
    Dim pattern$ = "(?x)" + vbCrLf +
                    "\b            #word boundary" + vbCrLf +
                    "(?'num'\d+)   #any number of digits" + vbCrLf +
                    "\b            #word boundary"
    '// Use "ReadLines" as it will lazily read one line at time
    For Each line In File.ReadLines("c:\test\output.txt")
        s = String.Join(",", Regex.Matches(line, pattern).
                                   Select(Function(e) e.Groups("num").Value))
        WriteLine(s)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Adding some explanation to your answer will help the person asking the question understand this code, and provides value to future visitors to this question.