# Import CVS coma separated Matrix into a Dynamics VB Matrix

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem, 
I have a Visual Basic project, it produces in the end,14 arrays of 7 integer numbers sorted from the more little to the more big. The problem is to compare them with the data lines present in a CSV file (or even the same file in excel depends on how easier the code is) separated by ";". Also the lines of the CSV file are composed of 7 numbers sorted from the more little to the more big, but the number of lines is variable, because with each use of the VB program, this must write a new line of 7 numbers in the CSV file. I thought the easiest way is to import the CSV file into a dynamic matrix in VB and compare the ARRAYs with each row of the matrix.

```
My Arrays are Integer:        
dim one (7) as integer         
dim two (7) as integer           
etc ... etc .... up to               
dim fourteen (7) as integer.
```

Can you give me a hand with the CVS file import and write in it?

Comment: To read a `CSV`-type file, you can use the [TextFieldParser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser) class. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53886089/7444103) (don't mind the regex thing). You can specify a non-standard separator. To append a line to the `CSV` file (it's a text file), you can use [File.AppendAllText](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext) or [File.AppendText](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext) or any other `File.Append-something` method.

Comment: There's a host of examples related to these methods.

Comment: Jimi thanks for the answer, tomorrow i wil try to read your suggest now i'm too much tired in italy is very late ....i hope to speak with you tomorrow for other some my doubt...good night see you tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I've resolve the import with that code:

Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                      FileIO.TextFieldParser("D:\Lista.csv")

```
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(";")

        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try

                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                Dim currentField As String
                For Each currentField In currentRow

                    c = (z + 1)
                    oldserie(c) = currentField
                    z = (c)

                Next
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                        FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
                "is not valid and will be skipped.")
            End Try
        End While
```

and for match the array with the matrix i've change idea and i've choose to match with one STRING ARRAY (oldserie(100000000)) each time with 6 number, starding from Lbound(oldserie)

and that is the only bad things because i must define oldserie like one array of string of 100000000 record......i cant use in dynamic array mode like

dim oldserie() as string
.